# How to view PDF file inside an Windows Phone application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pdf, windows-phone

I am developing an App for Windows Phone 7, in which I need to display a PDF file.
So basically I need any free library if available to view PDF files or any other way to achieve this.

Please guide me, any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways to open PDF file on Windows Phone:

1. Use "native" PDF viewer - Adobe Reader

   To do that, you need a location URI of your PDF file, and then you can either use the HyperlinkButton

   ```
   <HyperlinkButton Content="Click here to open PDF"
   NavigateUri="URI of your PDF" TargetName="_blank" Margin="10,60,0,0"/>
   ```

   or you could use the WebBrowser task to browse to the PDF which will invoke the PDF viewer:

   ```
   WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
   browser.URL = "URI of your PDF";
   browser.Show();
   ```
2. Use ComponentOne control for viewing PDFs

   http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/

   This will cost you some money, but should work OK.
3. Write your own control for rendering PDFs :)))

Answer (score 1):

The control from [Component One](https://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/) is the most highly rated one I've seen but it is not free.

You could also taker a look at http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-reading/ or http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/

Generally displaying PDF files is non-trivial and that is why there are no supported free controls available.